# how to specify dynamically last row number in row_spec kable()?

Tags: r, kable

I am generating different tables of different row length, so I want to have all the text of certain color,  but I have a question about the last row of my code in `row_spec`

```
 library(kable)
 library(kableExtra)

mtcars  %>% filter(cyl=4) %>% 
kable(align=c("l", rep("c", ncol(.)-1)),bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive")) %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"), full_width = TRUE) %>% 
  row_spec(0: nrow(.),  color = "black")
```

0: nrow(.) is not valid and I am not sure why, while rep("c", ncol(.)-1)) works.

Answer (score 2):

I think it doesn't work because `nrow(.)` returns `NULL`:

```
library(kable)
library(kableExtra)
mtcars  %>%
  kable(align=c("l", rep("c", ncol(.)-1)),bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive")) %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"), full_width = TRUE) %>% nrow(.)
#NULL
```

You could do this to color all rows:

```
  mtcars  %>%
    kable(align=c("l", rep("c", ncol(.)-1)),bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive")) %>%
    kable_styling(c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"), full_width = TRUE) %>% 
  row_spec(1:nrow(mtcars),color = "black")
```

Comment: Hi! The issue with it is what if I change number of rows in my cars after the pipe, so i actually have less or more rows then mtcars

Answer (score 2):

Even though not elegant, I would do it in two steps:

```r
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

# Step 1: Prepare data
temp <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl == 4) %>% 
  sample_n(sample(2:nrow(.), 1)) %>% 
  select(1:3)

# Step 2: Produce table
temp %>% 
  kable(align=c("l", rep("c", ncol(temp)-1))) %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", "hover", "condensed"), full_width = FALSE) %>% 
  # Format last row:
  row_spec(nrow(temp), color = "red", italic = TRUE, bold = TRUE)
```

[image]

[image]